# How to access process variables in an embedded form

Tags: camunda

I would like to access a process variable in an embedded form, but I am unable to do so. I went through the documentation at https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/embedded-forms/javascript/examples/ as well as through examples at https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/usertask/task-form-embedded-serialized-java-object and I think I got the hang of it, but the following code just does not work even though it seems it is 1:1 with the documentation.

Maybe the trouble is the variable I am trying to access is a LinkedHashMap (created as `mVariables = ['something': 'foo']` in Groovy)

The following snippet shows nothing in the Camunda Tasklist.

```
<form role="form" name="form" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
            camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('mVariables');
        });
        camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
            $scope.mVariables= camForm.variableManager.variable('mVariables').value;
        });
    </script>

    <h1>{{mVariables.something}}</h1>
    <p ng-bind="mVariables.something"></p>
<form>
```

Could anyone please provide a working minimal example of reading a process variable which is a LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LinkedHashMap cannot be passed as I proposed. It is written in the gray box at the top of this documentation site: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/embedded-forms/java-objects/

I solved my issue by splitting the Map into individual variables which can then be read in the embedded form as follows:

```
<form role="form" name="form" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
            camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('mVariableFoo');
            camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('mVariableBar');
        });
        camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
            $scope.mVariableFoo = camForm.variableManager.variable('mVariableFoo').value;
            $scope.mVariableBar = camForm.variableManager.variable('mVariableBar').value;
        });
    </script>

    <h1>{{mVariableFoo}}</h1>
    <p>{{mVariableBar}}</p>
<form>
```